# navbar toggler collapse not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

On clicking the button, the content drops down but it does not collapse on clicking the button again. Basically the toggle function isn't working.

```
 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" 
    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable" aria- expanded="false">

 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsable">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#particles">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#service">EVENTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#team">FACULTY ADVISORS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">OUR TEAM</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please post relevant CSS and JavaScript along with your example.

Comment: It's not clear whether you want to build a navbar with toggler or just a button to trigger collapsible div? http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/#toggler or http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/?

Comment: im building a navbar with toggler

Comment: Post *all* of the relevant code to repro the issue. The code you've provided isn't a properly structure Navbar and the HTML is invalid. For example, the button has no content and close tag.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that there’s a space in the middle of aria-expanded when there shouldn’t be. That may be causing the html to be malformed. Though without seeing the JS, it’s near impossible to diagnose the problem.